# Unused argument error with offset in column() for Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Following is my server.R script:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
})
```

Following is my ui.R script:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)


shinyUI(navbarPage("My Electronic CV", theme = shinytheme('readable'), inverse = TRUE,
        tabPanel("Overview Section",
            fluidRow(
                column(width = 4,
                    "4"
                ),
                column(width = 3, offset = 2,
                    "3 offset 2"
                )
            ) #closing bracket for fluidRow
        ) #closing bracket for tabPanel
    ) #closing bracket for navbarPage
) #closing bracket for shinyUI
```

With the above scripts, I keep getting the error:

```
Error in column(width = 4, "4") : unused argument (width = 4)
```

But I am really confused why this is so - I have spent the last couple of hours trying to find out why I face this.
Could anybody please point me in the right direction?

Comment: I was unable to replicate your issue.  What version of R, shiny, and shinythemes are you using?  I am using R 3.1.2, RStudio 0.98.1087, shiny 0.11.1, and shinythemes 1.0.1.  I did not get any error when I ran your code.

Comment: @PauldeBarros thanks so much for replying. This is very strange. I am using `R` 3.1.1, `shiny` 0.11.1, `shinythemes` 1.0.1. Now, I am updating R to latest. I had definitely started R several times with a clean session, and had still faced same problem. But now I am not! Just trying to figure out source of the error.

Comment: That is super weird.  So, the problem stopped when you updated from `R` 3.1.1 to the newest version?  Or did it persist, and then just stop randomly?  Since `shinythemes` was built under a more recent version of `R` (3.1.3), it would make sense that updating would fix it.  Also, are you using the app in a browser, and if so which one?

Comment: Ah, now I found out, following a helpful comment from Winston Chang: I tried commenting out certain packages I was loading as part of the application (the above code is a part of the app), and found that the `googleCharts` package may not be compatible. The package is found here: https://github.com/jcheng5/googleCharts Was actually a very nice package, but oh well. As soon as I load `googleCharts`, I get the reported error.

Comment: I am currently using the app from my R console, if I understood your question correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually the `googleCharts` package (which is currently, probably, under development - it is not finalised).

This chart causes the conflict for the `column` function from Shiny.

Package can be found here: https://github.com/jcheng5/googleCharts

Answer (score 3):

shiny and googlecharts both have the column() function. So, in order to solve this issue simply determine the package before the function name. For example:

```
shiny::column(width = 3, offset = 1, ...)
```

this should solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve this problem, first load the `shiny` package, then create a synonym for the function `column` such as `column2`, and then load `googlecharts`.  This makes `column2` associated with the `column` function in `shiny` but not the one in `googlecharts`.  Then use `column2` instead of `column` in the program.  Also, if `googleCharts` is already loaded when the app starts, you'll have to unload it before defining `column2`.  `ui.R` should look like this:

```
if("package:googleCharts" %in% search()) detach("package:googleCharts", unload=TRUE)
library(shiny)
column2 = column
library(shinythemes)
library(googleCharts)

shinyUI(navbarPage("My Electronic CV", theme = shinytheme('readable'), inverse = TRUE,
                   tabPanel("Overview Section",
                            fluidRow(
                              column2(width = 4,
                                     "4"
                              ),
                              column2(width = 3, offset = 2,
                                     "3 offset 2"
                              )
                            ) #closing bracket for fluidRow
                   ) #closing bracket for tabPanel
) #closing bracket for navbarPage
) #closing bracket for shinyUI
```